# Transforming Map[A,B] to Map[B, Set[A]] and back again

Tags: scala

I have a game board that is modelled as a Map[Location,Player]. For
some computations I wanted to transform that into
Map[Player,Set[Location]]. As an example, if we simplify and use symbols for
both keys and values, I want to transform this:

```
Map('a -> 'X, 'b -> 'O, 'c -> 'X, 'd -> 'O)
```

into this:

```
Map('O -> Set('b, 'd), 'X -> Set('a, 'c))
```

(I came up with one solution while writing this question, posted below. Would appreciate comments on that. Maybe there are there other, better ways?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After grouping, you can use `mapValues`:

```
m.groupBy(_._2).mapValues(_.keySet)
```

Comment: Be careful with mapValues (and filterKeys). They are lazy/return a view over the map.

Comment: I'm dealing with immutable maps. This should mean I'm OK, right?

Comment: In this specific case you're fine. Just keep in mind that mapValues returns a "view", so the closure for mapValues is executed each time the view is used. This is dangerous if the closure passed to mapValues has side effects. See this gist for an example: https://gist.github.com/davidandrzej/5006950

Answer (score 1):

Answering myself, since I came up with a fairly elegant solution while writing up the question:

```
grid.groupBy(_._2).map(x => x._1 -> x._2.keySet)
```

Would be interested to hear if there's better ways.

Answer (score -1):

```
m.foldLeft(Map.empty[Symbol, Set[Symbol]].withDefaultValue(Set.empty)) { case (acc, (k, v)) => acc.updated(v, acc(v) + k) }
```

Comment: I cannot see how this could be preferred over the other two solutions. It is neither more obvious what it does, nor more succinct  in doing it.

Comment: Is it perhaps because they're lazy / return views on the map as you commented on the accepted answer?